# ASP Classic: Pages in subfolders give 500 Internal Server error

Tags: iis, asp-classic, iis-7.5

Bit of background quick. I have to migrate an old website from an XP computer that has functioned as a webserver to our actual webserver since IT is going to disable the XP computer on the network. I know I will have to upgrade the code at some point, but since I was only given a couple days notice, I need to temporarily just migrate the whole site and work on it again later.

I have managed to configure the files and the web application on our server, and at least for the home page it loads fine, and looks correct. The issue arises when I try and access any of the other pages on the site. All I get is the generic "500 Internal Server error" page, both on client and server side. I've been digging for a while, but don't really have any ideas where else to look. I've tried enabling "Send errors to browser" and "Client side Debugging", but I haven't had any luck, and my time is starting to run out.

Any help that can be provided would be excellent.

Comment: How to enable debuging for classic ASP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138175/how-do-you-debug-classic-asp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014663/enable-logging-for-a-classic-asp-site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http 500 is a failure in the .asp code running on your server. It could be anything from version mismatch to missing files to missing/incorrect permissions. Have you looked in the IIS Server Logs?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your folder security is setup so that the IIS user can get to them.  You may have it set on the primary folder, but not on the sub-folders.

Comment: Looks like the root and subfolders have the same permissions. Good idea though, I didn't think about that.