# Does a 500 internal server error (for .asp subfolder page) write logs by default and ways to troubleshoot

Tags: windows, asp-classic, iis-10

services including http and .asp (diagnostic) page within a .net application throws 500 internal server error intermittently, the application pool running the service(s) uses a gmsa as an authentication identity. I checked event viewer on the server, but do not see any relevant logs.

validated the asp page on the server locally and below is a summary of detailed error info-

```
Detailed Error Information
Module IsapiModule
Notification ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler ASPClassic
Error Code 0x800700aa
```

I have re set the authentication to the gmsa account, but the error still persists intermittently.

question is, by default, do these error get logged in event viewer or IIS logs?
Any pointers to troubleshoot this issue?

Tried re setting the waveapplicationpool authentication to gmsa account.
checked the accounts associated with (under security tab), the physical path and it matches with a working server.

Comment: Setup FRT and below is the capture--

MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS

ModuleName
IsapiModule

Notification
EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER

HttpStatus
500

HttpReason
Internal Server Error

HttpSubStatus
0

ErrorCode
The requested resource is in use.
(0x800700aa)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable logging for a classic asp site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014663/enable-logging-for-a-classic-asp-site)

Comment: @user692942, I’ll try this and circle back.

Comment: Has the server used McAfee in the past if so [this might be worth a look](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/asp-500-error-and-error-code-0x800700aa-when-browsing-a-simple/ba-p/347256)?

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons for this error, you can try to change Application Pool Identity from the gMSA to system Built-in account.

If it still doesn't work, you can also use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/iis/troubleshoot-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7) to see detailed error messages.

Comment: I have tried this work around and it works, I am waiting for the next scheduled IISRESET as the error pops up each day right after the scheduled reset. However it would be good to understand the actual cause of this behaviour.